# Meaning of "I may never be able to do this"?

Tags: meaning, negation

The problem is, that I fail to unambiguously understand this phrase. There are two ways in which I can understand it (and a number of similar phrases):

1. I may never be able to do this = It's impossible for me to ever do this ('never' negates 'may')
2. I may never be able to do this = It's possible that I will never be able to do this. ('never' negates 'be able')

Which is the correct one?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between these two meanings? I don't understand your explanation of the difference.

Comment: @PeterShor `It's possible that I will never be able to do this` vs. `It's impossible for me to ever do this`. Maybe this time I am more clear. Question edited.

Comment: It's ambiguous.  It may be used to mean it's "unlikely" that I'll win an Olympic gold medal, it may be used with a sense that it's "nearly impossible" for me to win an Olympic gold medal, it may be used with a sense implying that there's only a slight chance that I *won't* be standing on the winner's platform.  Note that the two extremes are often used in a jocular sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both are potentially correct, and *context is everything.*

1. It hit me really hard when Fluffy passed away.  I may never be able to adopt another pet again.
2. I really need to concentrate on this.  If you don't stop breathing down my neck, I may never be able to disarm this bomb!

My first example parallels your first interpretation, and the second example your second interpretation.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, thanks. But the fun thing is that to my understanding, your first example parallels my second interpretation, and your second example parallels my first interpretation ;P

Answer (score 1):

***Modal verbs*** like "may" are often ambiguous. For exmaple, "may" is ambiguous between an expression of *possibility* and an expression of *permission*.

To make matter worse, when a negative like "not" is used with modals, there are ***scope ambiguities***. For example, "You may not run" can mean either:

- You are allowed to not-run.
- You are not allowed to run.

It's just a fact of English that these ambiguities exist. Only *context* can help you adjudicate them.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to understand it is with the rest of the context to help in achieving the usage.

"...I may never be able to do this, unless I earn money to pay for piano lessons..."

"...I may never be able to do this because there is simply not enough time left to <>".

Answer (score 1):

> I may never be able to do this

means that it is possible that I will never be able to do this.

If you want to say

> It's impossible for me to ever do this

that's what you have to say.

For example, I may never be able to hit a really good topspin backhand lob.  But, on the other hand, maybe I will, if I practice enough.

But to say:  I *may* never be able to play at Wimbledon is nonsense.  It implies that there is a possibility that I will become good enough to play at Wimbledon.  I *will never* be able to play at Wimbledon, no matter how much I practice.

Comment: @TimLymington  I am not sure about your edit.  If I wangled an invitation from a member of the All England Club, I could play at Wimbleton as a guest.  But I could never, never play in the Wimbleton tournament.